# How to correctly update a property of an object from a BackgroundWorker launched in the code of a methode of this object?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, backgroundworker

Don't now if title is clear. Here is a piece of code from a class in charge of managing a long operation :

```
public class LongProcess
{
    public delegate void RunningChangedEventHandler(bool running);

    public event RunningChangedEventHandler RunningChanged;

    private object runningLock = new object();
    public bool Running
    {
        get { lock (runningLock) { return mRunning; } }
        set
        {
            lock (runningLock)
            {
                RunningChanged.Invoke(value);
                value = mRunning;
            }
        }
    }

    public void start()
    {
        mWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        mWorker.DoWork += Bg_DoWork;
        mWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void Bg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Running = true;
        // Some things to do here ... but I need Running to be equals to true and it is not
    }
}
```

In main programm, I use LongProcess to start some tasks, it is completed by report progression etc ...

The only problem I'm facing, is that it seems that I'm unable to set "Running" to true. Even right after the call to the setter, it still keeps its old value.

Any help and explanations on how this works will be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your value and field the wrong way around in the setter. You need this:

```
public bool Running
{
    get { lock (runningLock) { return mRunning; } }
    set
    {
        lock (runningLock)
        {
            RunningChanged.Invoke(value);
            mRunning = value; // <=== LOOK HERE
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OH GOD ... I feel so dumb ! few hours without seeing such a fail ... Thanks a lot, you saved me a lot of time and you juste gave me another proof that I really need holidays ...